# Can I style a disabled control using CSS or script?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a HTML `div` element on a page that is updated when a `select` element on the page changes. Sometimes the `input` tags (text boxes) need to be disabled based on the selection.

Here is the problem: the project stakeholders like the functionality, they just think in the "disabled" state, the text box contents are too light and therefore unreadable. Can I apply CSS to a disabled control? Or should I be setting the text boxes to `readonly` and using some other CSS. This application is also using jQuery, if that helps. And ideas or suggestions here?

Answer (score 8):

```
input[type="submit"][disabled="disabled"]
{
    /* CSS here */
}
input[type="text"][disabled="disabled"]
{
    /* CSS here */
}
input[type="button"][disabled="disabled"]
{
    /* CSS here */
}
```

Works in every browser if the input tag is something like:

```
<input type="submit" disabled="disabled">
```

and if you want to change it when it is not disabled, just add this to your CSS

```
input[type="submit"]
{
    /* CSS here */
}
input[type="text"]
{
    /* CSS here */
}
input[type="button"]
{
    /* CSS here */
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can. In CSS:

```
input[disabled]{color:green}
```

Or jQuery:

```
$('input[disabled]').css('color','green');
```

UPDATE: This only works in gecko/webkit.

Comment: +1. I had an `<input type="image" ...>` which wasn't styled correctly when the disabled attribute was set/reset with jQuery. `input[disabled='disabled']` (css) didn't work in this scenario. `input[disabled]` did.

Answer (score 2):

Applying CSS to an element is not affected by whether the element is disabled.

Answer (score 2):

I would set them to readonly, as apparently you're wanting people to be able to read them, people may also want to select text from them for copy/paste, and selection is disabled as well when the text box is disabled. However, your CSS should work fine whether or not the element is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

If you have trouble with a non-overwritable style in a disabled element - Upper Stage points out that there is no limit on styling, and on second thought he may be right - you may be best off with giving the controls a `readonly` attribute and "manually disabling" it using `onfocus='this.blur();'`

Note that this will not work 100% like a disabled control: Its value will be submitted with the form.