# How to style Disabled Options in a form

Tags: css, forms

I'm using a form with a drop-down menu that contains some options disabled, so the users cannot select them. I'm trying to customize via css these elements but I have some problems with Chrome and IE7/8/9/10.

HTML:

```
<div class="formBody">
    <select  name="form[categoria][]"  id="categoria"  class="rsform-select-box">
      <option selected="selected" value="">Scegli una categoria</option>
      <option disabled="disabled" value="">Impresa </option>
    </select>
    <span class="formValidation">
        <span id="component50" class="formNoError">Scegli una categoria</span>
    </span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
select option[disabled] { color: #000; font-weight: bold }
```

This code works only with Firefox and doesn't work with Chrome and IE (all version).

Any idea to solve this problem?

---

Below the html code for select-box

```
<div class="formBody"><select  name="form[categoria][]"  id="categoria"  class="rsform-select-box" ><option selected="selected" value="">Scegli una categoria</option><option disabled="disabled" value="">Impresa </option><option  value="Servizi">Servizi</option><option  value="Informatica">Informatica</option><option  value="Commercio">Commercio</option><option  value="Telecomunicazioni">Telecomunicazioni</option><option  value="Editoria/Stampa">Editoria/Stampa</option><option  value="Meccanica/Elettrica">Meccanica/Elettrica</option><option  value="Alimentare">Alimentare</option><option  value="Chimica/Farmaceutica">Chimica/Farmaceutica</option><option disabled="disabled" value="">Edilizia </option><option  value="Tessile/Moda">Tessile/Moda</option><option  value="Mobili/Arredamenti">Mobili/Arredamenti</option><option  value="Alberghi/Ristoranti">Alberghi/Ristoranti</option><option  value="Trasporto/Logistica">Trasporto/Logistica</option><option  value="Finanza">Finanza</option><option  value="Altro">Altro</option><option disabled="disabled" value="">Professionista </option><option  value="Commercialista">Commercialista</option><option  value="Ragioniere">Ragioniere</option><option  value="Notaio">Notaio</option><option  value="Tributarista">Tributarista</option><option  value="Avvocato">Avvocato</option><option  value="Consulente del lavoro">Consulente del lavoro</option><option  value="Altro">Altro</option><option disabled="disabled" value="">P.A. Locale </option><option  value="Regione">Regione</option><option  value="Provincia">Provincia</option><option  value="Comune">Comune</option><option  value="Comunit&agrave; Montana">Comunit&agrave; Montana</option><option  value="ASL">ASL</option><option  value="CCIA">CCIA</option><option  value="Altro">Altro</option><option disabled="disabled" value="">P.A. Centrale </option><option  value="Associazione di categoria">Associazione di categoria</option><option  value="Privato">Privato</option><option  value="Altro">Altro</option></select><span class="formValidation"><span id="component50" class="formNoError">Scegli una categoria</span></span></div>
```

Comment: adding a .disabled class works well

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867743/can-i-style-a-disabled-control-using-css-or-script covers the problem generically, rather than just options in a dropdown.

Comment: I think you can't change "select" element in all browsers, but you can use some script that emulate/replace "select" element. Something like this http://www.benplum.com/formstone/selecter

Answer (score 65):

What you're looking for is this:

```css
select option:disabled {
    color: #000;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

[Here, have a fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/Cthulhu/zt0r42v7/1/z)

**Attention:** according to reports on the comments section, this solution does not work on OS X.

Comment: Just tested in Firefox and Chrome and works on both.

Comment: What versions are you on? Stable I'm seeing default behavior with no change.

Comment: Just tested in Chrome 43.0.2357.65 m, Firefox 38.0.1 and Firefox Developer Edition 40.0a2 (2015-05-24), it works just fine.

Comment: This doesn't work for me in Chrome too. What operating system are you on? I'm using OSX.

Comment: Just tested in IE, Chrome and Firefox, works perfect everywhere :)

Comment: For the guys using OSX, can you try adding `-webkit-appearance:none;` to the above CSS, and check if it works? @StefanKendall

Comment: If you run into an issue with setting the above code to white (#FFFFFF) where it goes back to using the disabled gray, try changing it to #FFFFFE. For some reason it overrides white but not 99% white.

Answer (score 15):

I used **:invalid** to solve my issue, description below:

So these answers do style the disabled option but only within the dropdown. Not if you wanted to display the disabled option at the top of the list as a "Please select".

Hope this helps others having a similar issue to what I had.

Basically, the select needs to be a required field for this to work:

```
<select required>
```

Assuming the option is at the top of the list:

```
<option disabled selected value="">Please select</option>
```

And your SCSS looking something like this:

```
select {

  // The select element is set to required
  // as long as the selected options value
  // is empty the element is not valid.
  &:invalid {
    color: gray;
  }

  // Styling for browsers which do support
  // styling select option elements directly
  [disabled] {
    color: gray;
  }

  option {
    color: black;
  }
}
```

So it's the :invalid which allows us to colour the disabled selected option.

Thanks to Markus Oberlehner for his post:

Blog post: https://markus.oberlehner.net/blog/faking-a-placeholder-in-a-html-select-form-field/

Codepen: https://codepen.io/maoberlehner/pen/WOWrqO

Comment: Excellent solution.

Answer (score 4):

There is a way to do this with CSS only. But you need to tweak your HTML to follow some rules:

- set your `select` to be `required`
- disabled options need to have empty value fields: `value=""`
- you need to style the `:valid` and `:invalid` states

Here is the markup:

```html
<select required>
    <option value="" selected disabled>Disabled default</option>
    <option value="" disabled>Just disabled</option>
    <option value="" >Empty but valid</option>
    <option value="a-value-here">Fully valid</option>
</select>
```

```css
select {
   width: 500px;
   padding: 10px;
}

select:invalid {
   background: red;
}

select:valid {
   background: green;
}
```

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/james2doyle/hw1m2cd9/

Now, when an option that is `disabled` and also `value=""`, the `:invalid` styling will be applied. You can see that empty values are still ok.

If only `select` supported `pattern`, then we could validate with regex instead. At the time of this comment, it does not and is only supported on input "text" types.

This solution should work on IE >= 10

Answer (score 3):

I do not think you can target an `option` tag using pure CSS; you can only modify a `select` tag.

- [Effort to modify a `select` tag](http://jsfiddle.net/W5B5p/).
- [Same effort to modify an `option` tag](http://jsfiddle.net/W5B5p/1/).

However, there are workarounds. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8430279/how-to-style-the-option-with-only-csst).

Comment: In Firefox the code works fine. I'm trying to found an alternative option that works with all browser.

Comment: You can target a option tag if it is disabled or you have added a class to it.
I have Edited @JSW189 fiddle and updated it

http://jsfiddle.net/W5B5p/110/

Comment: Styling of the color, background, and width in the fiddle only works in Firefox on OSX, not Chrome or Safari. Some default styling is applied to the disabled elements, however.

Answer (score 1):

```
<select>
    <option value="volvo" >Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="vw" disabled>VW</option>
    <option value="audi" class="colr">Audi</option>
    <option value="aaa">Something</option>
    <option value="ccc">Other</option>
    <option value="vw" disabled>VW</option>
    <option value="vvv">Apple</option>
    <option value="nnn" class="colr">Mango</option>
    <option value="cmmmcc">Plum</option>
</select>

option:disabled {
   background: #ccc;
   width: 500px;
   padding: 5px;
   }

option.colr {
   background: red;
   width: 500px;
   padding: 5px;
   }
```

Check the link
http://jsfiddle.net/W5B5p/110/

Comment: You need to have required in your <select> for it to work. `<select required>`

Answer (score 1):

I used a simple hack to make disabled options grey, hopefully someone finds it useful.

```
<label>
    <div id="disabledMask"></div>
    <select id="mySelect">
        <option disabled selected>Please Select</option>
        <option value="foo">Bar</option>
    </select>
</label>

<style>
    label {
        position: relative;
    }

    #disabledMask {
        position: absolute;
        background-color: #fff;
        opacity: 0.5;
        pointer-events: none;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        display: none;
    }
</style>

<script>
    var toggleMask = function(){
        var option = this.options[this.selectedIndex];
        var disabledMask = document.getElementById('disabledMask');
        disabledMask.style.display = option.disabled? 'block' : 'none';
    };

    var mySelect = document.getElementById('mySelect');
    mySelect.addEventListener('change', toggleMask);
    toggleMask.bind(mySelect)();
</script>
```

Here is a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jhavbzcx/

Disclaimer: depending on the styling of your select you may need to style the #disabledMask so as not to overlap the dropdown arrow.

Answer (score -2):

```
<select class="dropdown" name="contactMethod">
<option selected disabled>Contact method:</option>
<option class="dropdownplus"> E-mail: </option>
<option class="dropdownplus"> Website </option>
<option class="dropdownplus"> None</option>
</select>

<style>
.dropdown {
  background-color: rgba(195, 0, 97, 0.1);
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #CC0061;
  border-style: inset;
  color: grey;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  }

option.dropdownplus {
  color: black;
}
</style>
```

See img https://ibb.co/d9453b

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Answer (score -3):

```
var select = document.getElementsByTagName("select");

for(var i = 0;i < select.length; i++)
{
var el = select[i];
var optVal = el.options[el.selectedIndex].value
el.addEventListener('change', function () {
// Using an if statement to check the class
    if (optVal == "") {
        el.classList.remove('not_chosen');
    } else {
        el.classList.add('not_chosen');
    }
});
}
```

Comment: What exactly is this? CSS